# I cannot get jQueryUI buttonset and button to consistently work

Tags: jquery-ui, button

I've copied and pasted my code to jsfiddle.

What am I missing?

```
<div id="rx-button">
  <input name="rx" type="radio" value="rx-yes" id="rx-yes" checked="checked" />
  <label for="rx-yes">Rx</label>
  <input name="rx" type="radio" value="rx-no" id="rx-no" />
  <label for="rx-no">Not-Rx</label><br />
</div>
<div id="pr-button">
  <input id="pr" type="checkbox" /><label for="pr">Personal Record</label>
</div>​
```

`$('#rx-button').buttonset();`
`$('#pr-button').button();​`

http://jsfiddle.net/8ygnv/

Comment: The theme's CSS file? You also have a syntax error in your script (missing `);`). http://jsfiddle.net/8ygnv/7/

Comment: Thanks for the extra pair of eyes, yours works great. Do you want to turn this into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include one of the themes' CSS files for the jQuery UI widgets to render themselves correctly. I updated your fiddle with the UI Lightness theme file from Google's CDN repository.

You also have to close your `ready` handler properly to avoid syntax errors:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rx-button').buttonset();
    $('#pr-button').button();
});  // <-- Do not forget the closing parenthesis and the semicolon.
```

You will find the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ygnv/7/).